# Change Jupyter notebook working directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I open the notebook e.g. at home `home / user / Desktop / multifit-master / notebooks / CLS-DE.ipynb`.

And then type in the notebook (CLS-DE.ipynb) `%cd` I get:

```
home/user
```

Shouldn't this be the directory where I opened my notebook? It means :

```
home / user / Desktop / multifit-master / notebooks / CLS-DE.ipynb
```

How to make a notebook in the directory where I open it?

I want to see after typing %cd in CLS-DE.ipynb notebook this directory:

```
home / user / Desktop / multifit-master / notebooks / CLS-DE.ipynb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, `%cd` executes shell command `cd`, which means "go to home directory". Your home directory is `/home/user`.

If you want to change where `jupyter` saves notebooks:

- Define it when starting jupyter `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=home/user/Desktop/multifit-master/notebooks` for Jupyter or `jupyter-lab --notebook-dir=home/user/Desktop/multifit-master/notebooks` for JupyterLab.
- Switch to the required directory before starting `jupyter`.

To get what you want, i.e. "I want to see after typing %cd in CLS-DE.ipynb notebook this directory", you'd have to change `HOME` environment variable. I'd never go this way, as number of tools, scripts, libraries etc. might refer to you `HOME`. Changing it is likely to bring unforeseen consequences, with little benefit.

Answer (score 0):

option 1 : 
    open terminal, change path where ever you want to and then open jupyter notebook
    via terminal.
`jupyter notebook` 
Option 2 :
    u can use os.chdir

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal use cd to go in to the respective directory. Once there, type "jupyter notebook" in the terminal. This should open the notebook in that directory.

And to make sure that the notebook is open in the directory you wanted, type "%pwd". It means "print working directory".